# Network errors vs reachability

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift app where I am not sure how to handle network errors. I could catch the network errors in the completion blocks of all my network, but that would be a lot of added code. Alternatively, I could put `Reachability` in a singleton and add an error message to the top most view controller in the event of network failure.

Does anyone have any advice or experience with which approach is better?

Comment: Apple has said clearly which one they want you to use.

Comment: If adding proper handling of network errors requires "a lot of added code", that's a very strong indication you haven't abstracted your network layer well enough

Comment: Even if you monitor for network errors, you still need to handle network errors. For example failure can happen when request already sent, or network itself is fine, but say routing to a particular host is a problem, etc.

Comment: [This WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/715/) covers Apple's recommendations around Network.framework

Comment: @matt are you referring to the Network.framework, (wwdc video) that Paulw11 mentioned in his comment?